# Unable to start g++ using QProcess

Tags: c++, qt, qprocess

I want to compile a c++ file from Qt application by using QProcess. But it is not working, I don't see any .o or .exe file generated by the compiler.

Here is what I am doing -

```
QProcess *process = new QProcess(this);
QString program = "g++";
QStringList arguments;
//fileName is fetched from QFileDialog
arguments << fileName << "-o" << QFileInfo(fileName).path() + QFileInfo(fileName).baseName() + ".exe";

errorFilename = QFileInfo(fileName).baseName() + "_error.txt";

process->setStandardOutputFile(errorFilename);

connect(process, SIGNAL(finished(int)), this, SLOT(compiled()));
process->start(program, arguments);
```

Pleae tell me what's wrong with this code. I am working on windows 7.

Comment: Exactly what happens? Do you get an error, if so what, and when (compiling or running the code)?

Comment: do you have any spaces in your fileName path?

Comment: @MatsPetersson The `errorFile` generated is empty. I don't see any errors.

Comment: @louissmr The `fileName` is set by `QFileDialog::getOpenFileName()`.

Comment: ok, but your actual path has any spaces on it? I have had issues with QProcess and paths with spaces as arguments in Windows. The process is lauched fine, but the arguments are not ok.

Comment: @louissmr Oh, yes, it has spaces.

Comment: process->start(QString("g++ -o \"%1\" \"%2\"  ").arg(fileName.path).arg(fileName+"exe");

Comment: `QProcess` should wrap any arguments that have spaces inside quotes (http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qprocess.html#start).

Comment: Is `g++` in the `PATH` (in the environment of the Qt program)? What happen when you try to compile that same file with the same arguments from the command line?

Comment: @MichaelBurr Yes, it is in the `PATH`

Comment: @louissmr: actually, the start() overload taking QStringList() is usually more robust and to be preferred over manual quoting.

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld yes, and I am using this method in Linux and MacOSX, but at least in some versions of Qt (I can't remember now the exact version number) is not working properly in Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that errors don't go to `stdout`, they go to `stderr`. Try using:

```
process->setStandardErrorFile(errorFilename);
```

Also `QFileInfo::path()` won't have a path separator at the end, so you'll need to add one when concatenating the path with the base filename:

```
QFileInfo finfo(fileName);

arguments << fileName << "-o" << QFileInfo( QDir(finfo.path()), finfo.baseName() + ".exe").filePath();
```